# Call a function using bind in tk text widget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have been using a `tk text widget` and I was wondering how to call a function if the user types a certain letter. For example if the user types **a** I want it to call a function and if the user types **b** I want to call another function. I tried to use bind but I don`t know how to use it for my situation.

Comment: have you read any documentation or searched for answers? Show us the research you've already done so. If you have code that doesn't work, show us the code. As written, your question is too broad and can be answered by almost any tkinter tutorial or book.

Comment: Although I have just given you the answer, Bryan is right in saying you should really research for an answer before coming to help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use some simple code like this:

```
root = Tk()

text = Text(root, **kw)
text.pack()

def text_print(*args):
    print('Hello World!')

text.bind('a', text_print)
```

This will work the way you want however it only runs when the Text widget is active, like if it's selected and you have the flashing line, and when the "a" key is pushed down, for more I would recommend checking out this: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm

Hope that helps!